# How do I get Passenger to deploy a RoR app on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-12.04, passenger

I'm trying to get a simple 'hello world' RoR app deployed using Apache/Passenger on Ubuntu 12.04 (via Linode). I followed the directions on the Phusion Passenger documentation site. I get the Passenger error screen that says:

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started
```

- The backtrace is here: http://pastebin.com/Sr4PaQvB
- My apache virtual host config is here: http://pastebin.com/q2vb0hX8

One thing that is confusing me is why Passenger is not using the ruby (and gems) that I have installed via RVM even though I specifically use `SetEnv` and 'PassengerRuby` to tell it where to look. I appreciate any advice! Thanks!

Comment: You should display the entire error message, not just the backtrace. Having only the backtrace is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Passenger wasn't loading up the right ruby/gems was because RVM wasn't installed correctly. I reinstalled RVM and reconfigured my app setup for the correct gems and all was well.